# TextView not working in RelativeLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am unable to see my TextView on the display. I have placed LinearLayout and TextView in RelativeLayout, But only LinearLayout can be seen and not the TextView

Please help me with this code. Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.dakshesh.happybirthday.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Bahubali"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where you want to display the `TextView` ? On top of the view or at bottom of the view ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Please paste your code instead of including links with it.

Comment: Use `ScrollView` to get the `TextView`

Comment: The code seems to be fine.

Answer (score -1):

its because you haven't put your textview below linearlayout.
so textview overlapping on linearlayout and that's why you cant see it.
Just give id to linearlayout

```
android:id="@+id/linear"
```

and write this line inside textview..

```
android:layout_below="linear"
```

Comment: Have you understand the question? Its the Linearlayout which is taking whole space not textview.So placing the textview below linear layout will have no impact.Still textview will not be visible

Comment: why not use below textView?